# eclipse cvs load error

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I just installed eclipse indigo and when I open cvs perspective I get the following error.

```
Could not create the view: Plug-in org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.repo.RepositoriesView.
```

Please help.

```
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui (594).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewDescriptor.createView(ViewDescriptor.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:327)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:534)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.updateContainerVisibleTab(PartStack.java:1648)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:659)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:570)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:272)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:981)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.onActivate(WorkbenchPage.java:2714)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$27.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:3023)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setActivePage(WorkbenchWindow.java:3004)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$20.runWithException(WorkbenchWindow.java:2290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
```

Comment: At first, I thought there was a typo (**ccvs**) but that package actually exists. At the bottom of the stack trace is this error: `Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone` This suggests that there is another error (either the stack trace is longer or there was an error further up in the log file). Can you please check this?

Comment: thanks Aaron, am starting with that point.

Comment: Same problem when I had imported preferences from older Eclipse, but didn't installed the CVS plugin on the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the stack trace is this error:

```
Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone
```

This suggests that there is another error (either the stack trace is longer or there was an error further up in the log file)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, a corrupted JRE caused it. Reinstalled fresh one.

Thanks Aaron, I couldn't make your comment as answer ;)